# Give myself permissions for all files in / without bricking my computer?

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

How do I give myself read/write/execute permissions for all files in the root directory without making the system unusable?

Would this command do it?

```
sudo chown -R jacob3 /
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /
```

This is for my personal computer, where I (jacob3) am the only user. No private information is stored on my device without being encrypted.

The reason I want to do this is to avoid having to use sudo.

Also, I'm not actually going to do this. This is more of a hypothetical, in the sense of how this would be done.

Comment: This command will make your system unusable. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @DougO'Neal I want to access anything on my device without having to use sudo.

Comment: Then just log in as `root` or change your user account's UID to zero.  And then heed our advice to just reinstall from scratch after you brick your system.

Comment: Did you consider configuring `sudo` (in `/etc/sudoers`) to avoid typing any password?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `sudo` so bad that you would rather brick your system?

Comment: @Yoshimaster Are you a Windows user used to the one-click admin "auth" getting started on GNU/Linux? Generally speaking, behaving in Linux as if it were a Windows system is a bad idea. They're different.

Comment: FYI - You can't "brick" a computer by changing permissions of files.

Comment: *"I want to access anything on my device without having to use sudo."*  (1) Use sudo.  (2) Or, log in as root.  Do either of those fit your hypothetical?  (If not, **your hypothetical is self-defeating.**  Hypothetically, how can I hit my arm with a sledgehammer really hard without breaking it, and without using any protective gear?)

Comment: @rmmaddy You can, however, very easily render it almost entirely unusable and unreachable, at which point "bricked" becomes a meaningless distinction.

Comment: If you find yourself typing `sudo` "too" often in a CLI session, don't even think about modifying file permissions to get rid of the need to do that. Instead, if you really must to keep your sanity, type `sudo su` to start a root CLI session. Even then, know what you're doing and that even small typos in commands run as root can have disastrous effects. **With great power comes great responsibility.**

Comment: Also, whatever you do, make sure you have a recent and working (i.e. tested) backup of your data.

Comment: @das-g why not `sudo -s`?

Comment: If you really *really* still want to do this after reading everything that everybody else has said, look into using ACLs.  (1) They are almost surely safer than `chown`ing and `chmod`ing everything.  (2) They may be somewhat safer than running as root — especially if you use some common sense and do it only to the files that you really need access to.  (3) They let you keep using your own UID.

Comment: @roaima `sudo -s` is of course just as fine. (And maybe even preferable?)

Answer (score 43):

Changing the ownership of all files on the system is a *very very very bad* idea.  Consider just for starters that the first command you propose will change the owner of `sudo`, which means it will no longer have root privileges to allow you to run the second command.

Ponder this.

You are immediately breaking fundamental tools and you haven't even finished doing what it is you think you want to do.

I would strongly suggest that you instead think about what the problem is that you are trying to solve for which you suggest your proposed solution.

`sudo` is provided for a reason; avail yourself of it.

Comment: I want to access anything on my device without having to use sudo.

Comment: `sudo` is provided to protect you from yourself.  However, if you _really_ want to do this, just change the UID of your account (in `/etc/passwd`) to zero, or simply log in as the root user.  However, I can offer you nearly 100% certainty that you will inadvertently render your system unusable at some point, and the only advice you will get after you do this to yourself will be to restore from a backup (you _will_ be keeping backups, right?) or to reinstall from scratch once this happens.

Comment: Edited question.

Comment: @Yoshimaster as others have said, it's a horrible idea but even if you do want to access anything without `sudo`, why would you want to give write permissions to everything (many things should not be writeable) and why in the world would you want to make everything executable?

Comment: @DopeGhoti The chance to render your system unusable by using root as the default login is not greater than rendering a Windows95 system unusable by the standard user with admin rights, is it? That is, it has happened in the past, but not terribly often. The main reason for restricted user rights is multiple users. Of course, if you are a power user and run funny scripts with the wrong glob or in the wrong path you may wreck havoc; but in all reality the user who wants to be root as a default is the least likely power user candidate and will just run a mail and http GUI client from KDE.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider several tools require certain files to have specific permissions. Some of these tools would not work at all. Other tools makes assumptions of the permissions the files have and break in unexpected ways. sudo, ssh, lightdm are some of these tools.

Comment: @Braiam [Somehow my original comment seems to have disappeared.] I was referring to Yoshi's comment that as root you'll likely brick your system by mistake at some point. I was saying that in Win95 and earlier we all were root, all the time, and didn't have fatalities that often.-- By contrast, it is totally obvious, as Dope points out in his answer, that the OP's idea to change owner and/or permissions system-wide will not work.

Comment: On the contrary; I have a background in tech support, and I can't tell you how many peoples' systems I had to recover from removing `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32` because "there was a lot of crap in there I never use".

Answer (score 15):

As DopeGhoti says, the classic way to do this is to log in as root.  There is also a history of giving a second user other than `root` the UID 0.  This gives them the root privileges, but with their own `passwd` settings e.g. password and home directory.

Modern desktop software e.g. gdm will be set up to refuse logins as root / UID 0.  There may be methods to gainsay this in some cases.

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Enabling_Root_User_For_GNOME_Display_Manager

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Enable_root_login_in_GDM

---

Attempting to maintain full access for a user which is *not* UID 0, will be stymied because the permissions of system files are set according to the packages they are installed from.  When you install new packages, or upgrade existing ones, it will set permissions on new files.

There will also be restrictions, e.g. on the files you don't own, you won't be able to change their mode including the executable bit.

Any daemons that rely on setuid programs would be broken.

Software which checks for sensible permissions on files containing authentication secrets or authentication configuration (e.g. sshd authorized_keys), will be broken.

It wouldn't make a lot of sense to try and do it this way.

Comment: Oh and furthermore, this will hose binaries that really need to be setuid.

Comment: Not to mention that several pieces of software are designed to throw a massive fit if the permissions on their config files are not secure.

Answer (score 5):

Reiterating the above because it can't be said often enough: **DO NOT DO THIS**.

Even aside from the utterly ridiculous security risks you're inviting and the complete dismantling of every failsafe inherent in the access control design, this will break various parts of your system because certain bits of software are *designed* to throw a literal fit if they detect that a config file containing sensitive information is not properly secure.

Treat `sudo` the way you'd treat your seatbelt or bike helmet. Minor inconvenience to put on before every trip, but the first time you make a mistake on the road when you didn't wear it will be your last.

Comment: You're making a number of assumptions here. There are in fact plenty of times when this would be absolutely fine, such as a stripped back virtual machine that lives for all of twenty minutes per provisioning and has only a very specific set of tasks to achieve. Doing everything as root on one of those is not only perfectly safe, but perfectly natural. Not everybody is always working on a PC or a server connected to the internet.